# Primefaces Calendar <f:ajax> and <p:ajax> issue

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am currently facing issue using  with primefaces Calendar control

My requirement is to invoke a java method on change of the Calendar control value either from the input box or using the button and also pass a set of parameters(Java object and the field id) to the java method.

below is the code that I have implemented and it is not working

```
<p:calendar showOn="button" id="effectiveDt" navigator="true" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" 
    styleClass="overrideable" value="#{coverage.startDate}">
    <f:ajax event="change" render="hiddenStartDt" onevent="myEvent" listener="#{certInquiry.ovrrrideListener}"/> 
        <f:attribute name="covg" value="#{coverage}" />
        <f:attribute name="field" value="StartDate" />
</p:calendar>
```

here **myEvent** is a java script method which will be called after the ajax is completed where i am checking the ajax status is success and performing some action.

method signature of the java method is.

**public void overrideListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) **

I tried with all kinds of methos signatures like

```
public overrideListener(ValueChangeEvent e)
 public overrideListener(ActionEvent e)
 public ovrrrideListener(DateSelectEvent event)
```

nothing was working for me

I have tried using  also even this was not working
I also tried using valueChangeListener if the method gets called but it was not invoking the method

this is working for  and  fields using the

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox class="overrideable" 
                    value="#{coverage.clIndicator}">
    <f:ajax event="change" render="hidgenLiabClaimsMdInd" onevent="myEvent" listener="#{certInquiry.overrideListener}"/> 
                    <f:attribute name="covg" value="#{coverage}" />
                    <f:attribute name="field" value="ClIndicator" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<h:inputText id="genLiabEachOccAmt" value="#{coverage.eachOccAmt}"
            class="amt_field overrideable">
    <f:ajax event="change" render="hidgenLiabEachOccAmt" onevent="myEvent" listener="#{certInquiry.overrideListener}"/> 
            <f:attribute name="covg" value="#{coverage}" />
            <f:attribute name="field" value="EachOccAmt" />
</h:inputText>
```

Please help me in solving this issue for the Calendar component.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a red herring, but `ovrrrideData` is definitely not the same as `overrideListener` nor `ovrrrideListener`. Please revise your code snippet carefully before posting it.

Comment: my apologies for missing it i have tried using different methods and missed changing it before posting I have updated it now

Answer (score 1):

Make the `ajax event="dateSelect"` and you should get the date value in your BB when you use `ovrrrideListener(DateSelectEvent event)`.